# Generate memory dump when Java process is killed by OOM reaper

Tags: java, linux, memory-leaks, centos

I have a Java application on CentOS 8 which is killed by OOM Reaper:

```
[3282541.776491] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/tomcat.service,task=java,pid=368592,uid=1001
[3282541.778447] Out of memory: Killed process 368592 (java) total-vm:4134400kB, anon-rss:1433996kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1001
[3282541.856296] oom_reaper: reaped process 368592 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Problem is that it is not generating `OutOfMemoryError` so I can't use `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` setting to generate dump when application is dying.

Is it possible to get memory dump when application is killed by OOM Reaper?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such thing as the OOM killer would be called if the OS thinks it's about to die if it doesn't get memory freed fast and generating a heap dump might add to the burden. However, there might still be a way I'm not aware of. What we did at a previous job was basically trigger a heap dump if memory was filling up enough to actually trigger the OOM reaper. This was not perfect but could provide a hint. Also note that your Java application might not be the culprit since it obviously didn't fully use the heap space available to it.

Comment: What if you write a `try..catch(Throwable)` and throw yourself the `OutOfMemoryError`. Would that trigger that `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`?